# How does Stack handle changes to optimization levels?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If I change the optimization level ghc option, and then `build`, does Stack recompile all dependencies with the updated optimization level? I have not noticed this happening, but I don't know if I'm missing something.

If Stack does not recompile dependencies with the updated optimization level, how can I get it to do so?

Comment: Try `--force-dirty`.

Comment: Dunno about stack, but with cabal, dependencies choose their own optimization level in their cabal file and you don't have any control over that at the top level. I would bet stack is similar. Generally this is what you want: the library author has thought a lot more than you about what tradeoffs to make; and, even in your unoptimized debugging builds, you want the fast version of the library because probably the bug is in your code, not the library.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think it works as you described. I built my project with -O2, but only noticed a difference in my benchmark after I updated one of my `extra-deps` cabal file to also use -O2.